# Making a clickable SVG that doesn't trigger a mouseLeave

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, events, react-bootstrap

What I'm trying to do:

- when you hover over the row, color changes and a SVG appears
- you can click the SVG (currently displays 'clicked' in console) to trigger a function (needs to support triggering external functions too, not just ones that need to be defined inside script tags inside svg, so props functions for example)
- when your mouse leaves, the row reverts to original form

Problems:

- hovering over the SVG button triggers a mouseLeave (leaves the row)
  if pointer-events is not set to none. If it is set to none, the SVG
  button becomes unclickable.
- onClick inside SVG doesn't seem to support external functions (props
  functions for example)

Would appreciate help with this.

```js
const { Container, Row, Col} = ReactBootstrap;
function Library(props){
  
  function handleMouseEnter(e){
    e.style.background = 'blue';
    var targetNode = e.querySelector(`#content`);
    ReactDOM.render(                
      <svg  width="0.75rem" height="0.75rem" className="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 472.615 472.615" fill="white">   
        <polygon onClick={e => console.log('clicked')} points="50.273,0 50.273,472.615 422.342,236.308"/>
      </svg>
      , targetNode);
  }
  
  function handleMouseLeave(e){
    e.style.background = '';
    var targetNode = e.querySelector(`#content`);
    ReactDOM.render(                
      "hover over me and click the button!"
      , targetNode);
  }
  
  return(
  <Container>
    <Row 
    onMouseEnter={e => handleMouseEnter(e.target.closest('.row'))}
    onMouseLeave={e => handleMouseLeave(e.target.closest('.row'))}
    >
      <Col>
        <div id="content">
          hover over me and click the button!
        </div>        
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Library/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.row{
background:red;
}
svg{
pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create file `.svg` and store your svg on that file.
example

`Icon.svg`

```
    <svg  width="0.75rem" height="0.75rem" className="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 472.615 472.615" fill="white">   
        <polygon points="50.273,0 50.273,472.615 422.342,236.308"/>
    </svg>
```

And you can render your `Icon.svg` into your component example:

`YourComponent.jsx`

```
import { ReactComponent as Icon } from "./Icon.svg";

const YourComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon onClick={e => console.log('clicked')} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

and congratulation now you can click your `Icon.svg`.

in best practice if you wanna import some `.svg` images you should import as `ReactComponent`

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tested this out and it doesn't answer my question completely. The SVG is clickable, theoretically, but the issue is that if I don't set the style of the SVG to pointer-events:none; the SVG disappears from the row before I can click it because it triggers a onMouseLeave event. If I set pointers-events:none; the SVG doesn't trigger onMouseLeave so it remains on-screen like in the code I posted, but this style disables all mouse interactions so it's unclickable now.

Comment: Though I think your answer will help me use external functions onClick, like prop functions etc...

Comment: check my another answer...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this using `useState` for conditional rendering

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { ReactComponent as Icon } from "./Icon.svg";

const YourApp = () => {
  const [onHover, setOnHover] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setOnHover(true);
  };
  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setOnHover(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={onHover ? { background: "blue" } : { background: "red" }}
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    >
      {onHover && <Icon onClick={(e) => console.log("clicked")} />}
      hover over me and click the button!
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed the problem by editing onMouseLeave to check if the element that triggered it was a SVG or one of it's children, if it is, then count it as a false positive. Now the button is clickable and doesn't disappear if you hover over it.

```js
const { Container, Row, Col} = ReactBootstrap;
function Library(props){
  
  function handleMouseEnter(row){
    row.style.background = 'blue';
    var targetNode = row.querySelector(`#content`);
    ReactDOM.render(                
      <svg onClick={e => console.log('clicked')} width="0.75rem" height="0.75rem" className="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 472.615 472.615" fill="white">   
        <polygon points="50.273,0 50.273,472.615 422.342,236.308"/>
      </svg>
      , targetNode);
  }
  
  function handleMouseLeave(e, row){
    if(e.relatedTarget.tagName === 'svg' || e.relatedTarget.tagName === 'polygon') return
    row.style.background = '';
    var targetNode = row.querySelector(`#content`);
    ReactDOM.render(                
      "hover over me and click the button!"
      , targetNode);
  }
  
  return(
  <Container>
    <Row 
    onMouseEnter={e => handleMouseEnter(e.target.closest('.row'))}
    onMouseLeave={e => handleMouseLeave(e, e.target.closest('.row'))}
    >
      <Col>
        <div id="content">
          hover over me and click the button!
        </div>        
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Library/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.row{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```